# How do I show both Training loss and validation loss on the same graph in tensorboard through keras?

Tags: keras, tensorboard

I'm using Keras with the Tensorflow back end to train a CNN, and I'm using tensorboard to visualize the loss functions and accuracy. I would like to see the loss function of both the training data and validation data on the same graph, but I've only found ways to do so when using Tensorflow and not through keras.

Is there a way to do so?

Edit 1:
I tried writing loss/acc in the Regex but instead of putting both of the graphs together it shows them side by side like so:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyUPZ.jpg

Ive added what I use to log to tensor board:

```
tbCallBack=keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir='C:\\logs', histogram_freq=0, write_graph=False, write_images=True, embeddings_freq=0, embeddings_layer_names=None, embeddings_metadata=None)

model.fit_generator(train_generator,
                steps_per_epoch=x_train.shape[0] // batch_size,
                epochs=epochs,
validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
```

Comment: Have you ever found your answer?

Comment: Afraid not, the best I found was to save the model into history while training, and then using matplotlib or similar to plot each time.
its not ideal, but I haven't found a better way.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a regex in the text box in the upper left corner of the Tensorboard window.

Add `acc` for accuracy of both train/validation data. Add `loss`for the loss values. This works for me for Keras as well as Tensorflow.

Got this from this nice tutorial on TB: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eBbEDRsCmv4

As a code snippet I use this:

```
logdir = "_tf_logs/" + now.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S") + "/"
tb = TensorBoard(log_dir=logdir)
callbacks=[tb]
...
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, validation_data=val_data, epochs=10, verbose=2, callbacks=callbacks)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! I've addressed what you wrote in an edit since its easier then through here.

also the link you shared links to a google search and not the tutorial you tried to link.

Comment: Thanks. And the link is corrected. Thanks too for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

I found this from Github for this exact purpose but without using tensorboard. Hope this helps!

[live loss plot for keras](https://gist.github.com/stared/dfb4dfaf6d9a8501cd1cc8b8cb806d2e)